# using Barcode and barcode scanner to auto fill the web form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, barcode

I am developing an e-commerce web site using asp.net MVC4, it need to fill the product form(eg. product name, price, etc) and save to database, and i know we can use a barcode scanner to do such stuff(scan the barcode, the form will be filled programmatically). What is the key word that i should google? Any example?

Answer (score 0):

Steps could be:

- call webcam in web browser
- scan and decode barcode
- analyze the result. probably you can make a data structure like
  {"name":xx, "price":xx, etc}. extract data from result and fill them into product form.